# Post with Mixed Payload, keep getting "Cannot find end boundary"

Tags: python, python-requests, payload

I'm trying to insert some timeseries data into mindsphere.
At this link under "Uploading Data" you can find the example that i'm foollowing [Mindsphere Guide](https://documentation.mindsphere.io/MindSphere/howto/howto-agent-upload-data.html#uploading-time-series-data)

My code in python is the following:

```
import request    
# load data
url = "https://southgate.eu1.mindsphere.io/api/mindconnect/v3/exchange"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token["access_token"],
    "Content-Type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=B00",
}
payload = """--B00
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=B01

--B01
Content-Type: application/vnd.siemens.mindsphere.meta+json

{
    "type": "item",
    "version": "1.0",
    "payload": {"type": "standardTimeSeries", "version": "1.0","details": {"configurationId": ""}}
}
--B01
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
        "timestamp": "2023-07-05T20:45:03.780Z",
        "values": [
            {"dataPointId": "1688546678249","value": "9856","qualityCode": "0"},
            {"dataPointId": "1688546678248","value": "3766","qualityCode": "0"}
        ]
    }
]
--B01--
--B00--
\r\n 
"""


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print("Post Response: ", response.status_code, response.text)
```

I tried to change many times the space and the return in my payload string, but I always get the following response:

```
Post Response:  400 {"id":"7f9bc9f32a194fd4a837b6fcf7ac8700","message":"Cannot find end boundary <\r\n--B01--> after index 270"}
```

I'm quite confused, maybe I should insert the header into the payload to let better parsing the multipart payload, but i don't know how to do.

I also tried to remove /r/n indicated in the documentation, but it doens't work.

Does someone has some suggestions?